# How to add list object to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add list object to Dictionary.
Code:

```
 for line in file:
     splitObj=line.split("=") #split a line xxx= yyy using = delimiter
     listObj=list(splitObj)
     chip_mem.update(listObj[0], listObj[1])
```

This didn't help. Can anyone please let me know how to add the contents of the list to the dict as a `key, value` pair?

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in file:
    pieces = line.split("=")
    chip_mem[pieces[0]] = pieces[1]
```

Note that there's no reason to call `list()` on the result of `.split`, since it's already a list.

Note that if not all of your lines have `=` signs in them, you might need to check for this:

```
for line in file:
    pieces = line.split("=")
    if len(pieces) > 1:
        chip_mem[pieces[0]] = pieces[1]
```

Comment: This shows : Indexerror: list index out of range error. Please advice

Comment: That means that at least one of your lines doesn't have an `=` in it, and thus isn't returning two pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get a key and a value made for each thing in your list by splitting them on the equal sign, you can always do:

```
for k,v in list.split("="):
  mydict[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

dict [update](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method requires other key-value pairs, see:

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> mydict.update({'param': 'value'})
>>> print mydict # prints{'param': 'value'}
```

So in your case, for instance:

```
myfile = open("config.txt")
lines = myfile.readlines()
chip_mem = {}

for line in lines:
    parts = line.strip().split("=")
    chip_mem.update({parts[0]: parts[1]})

print chip_mem
```

Comment: This method is giving me Indexerror: list index out of range . However, when i try to use chip_mem.update({parts[0]}) alone..i see that the "keys", if i use chip_mem.update({parts[0]:parts[]1}), it throws the above error.

Comment: @user3663098 As Amber has commented, "That means that at least one of your lines doesn't have an = in it, and thus isn't returning two parts." In addition I showed how to use update method, especially.